# Connecting a three phase drive - Should N connect with L3?

Tags: three-phase, drive

I have a simple question. I'm going to connect a three phase motor.

'Three phase source -> drive unit - > three phase motor'

But between the three phase source, should I connect N with L3, or should I ignore the N line?

The drive's brand is VLT Micro Drive FC 51 Danfoss

[image]

[image]

Comment: Connecting L3 with N will surely give sparks and blow the fuse at minimum, or spew molten copper on you. Please try to understand what you are doing very carefully. I am not an electrician, but I interpret the manual so that for 1-phase you L and N as marked, or, for 3-phase, you connect L1 L2 L3 as marked, noting that there is no neutral connection for 3-phase input.

Comment: @justme Thank you. I did interprent the manual wrong then.

Comment: such works should only be carried out by educated, trained and certified persons. You also do not work on your car's brakes - do you?

Comment: @schnedan I'm a car mechanic.

Comment: don't know if this is true for cars, but for truck-brakes you need a extra certificate + regular (2 years) renewing courses... at least in germany. a normal mechanic is not allowed to do that. Its the same with 230V (110V). A normal electrician is not allowed to do such works (only with guidance). You need a special training to accept a installation prior to power it for the first time - and it might be hard, but your question shows: you should not do such works. sorry

Comment: just to be safe, ask a professional to control your work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The L1, L2, and L3 markings are for using three phase power.

The L and N markings are for using single phase.

You are using three phase, so ignore the L and N markings.

For three phase, the controller doesn't have a neutral wire input.

Answer (score 0):

Better do nothing before you know more about your motor. Can you post the typeshield of the motor and a picture of the connection board? How are "plattes"set? Even better ask an electrian!

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the motor. The confusion is on the VFD power input. JRE's answer is correct.

Comment: Also this does not answer the question.